# zIndex of map label has no effect if it's used with GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I am using [Google map label](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label) to display some property from GeoJSON data on GeoJSON layer. The layer has some dark color and the label is being created behind the GeoJSON data layer due to that the map label looks blurry. I tried to apply bigger zIndex for label than data layer but it has no effect. Check out the issue in plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/KvhIoRoibsbKk9e4k1Ch?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="geojson.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<script src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-map-label/src/maplabel-compiled.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function(NgMap) {
  var vm = this;

  NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    vm.map = map;
    vm.map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
      return({
        fillColor: feature.getProperty('fill') ? feature.getProperty('fill') : 'transparent',
        strokeWeight: 0.5,
        fillOpacity: feature.getProperty('fillOpacity') ? feature.getProperty('fillOpacity') : 0.5,
        zIndex: 1000
      });
    });
    vm.map.data.addGeoJson(geojson);
    vm.map.data.forEach(function (feature) {
      var centroid = feature.getProperty('centroid');
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(centroid.coordinates[1], centroid.coordinates[0]);

      var mapLabel = new MapLabel({
          text: feature.getProperty('Shale_play'),
          position: myLatlng,
          map: vm.map,
          fontSize: 16,
          align: 'center',
          minZoom: 5,
          fontColor: '#0000ff',
          zIndex: 5000
      });

      mapLabel.set('position', myLatlng);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <ng-map zoom="8" center="35.3944545,-92.78723"></ng-map>
</body>
</html>
```

geojson.js

```
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "geology_tightOilGas_eia20160311",
            "fillOpacity": "0.8",
            "fill": "#00aa22",
            "Basin": "Arkoma",
            "Lithology": "Shale",
            "Shale_play": "Fayetteville",
            "Source": "EIA",
            "Area_sq_mi": 5852.69474734,
            "Area_sq_km": 15158.4098071,
            "Age_shale": "Mississippian",
            "centroid": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-92.78723, 35.3944545]
            }
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-94.277701, 35.202423],
                        [-94.382715, 35.322647],
                        [-94.393411, 35.533806],
                        [-94.36331599899995, 35.638342],
                        [-94.24130399899997, 35.682679],
                        [-94.023528, 35.690577],
                        [-93.875907, 35.691057],
                        [-93.491065, 35.684045],
                        [-92.952118, 35.658092],
                        [-92.664754, 35.666656],
                        [-92.30350699899998, 35.677098],
                        [-91.918848, 35.628261],
                        [-91.475479, 35.601242],
                        [-91.181049, 35.59428500100006],
                        [-91.274519, 35.529656],
                        [-91.388323, 35.449603],
                        [-91.544307, 35.31595599900004],
                        [-91.73661700099996, 35.176988],
                        [-91.867632, 35.102377],
                        [-92.012094, 35.097852],
                        [-92.29381300099999, 35.102714],
                        [-92.709335, 35.13337],
                        [-93.396545, 35.153332],
                        [-94.01489300099996, 35.168451],
                        [-94.277701, 35.202423]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following workaround. Instead of the `js-map-label` library and its `MapLabel` object you can use native `google.maps.Marker` object with custom icon and label. The trick is: as a custom icon URL you can provide an URL of empty png image and additionally you can specify a position where the label should appear.

Your code where you create the label should be changed to the following

```
vm.map.data.forEach(function (feature) {
    var centroid = feature.getProperty('centroid');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(centroid.coordinates[1], centroid.coordinates[0]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: vm.map,
        title: feature.getProperty('Shale_play'),
        icon: {
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Blank.png"
        },
        label: {
            text: feature.getProperty('Shale_play'),
            color: '#0000ff',
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: "16px"
        }
    });
});
```

The result that I got with this code is shown in screenshot

[image]

Have a look at complete example in plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ciuPVzjNcVIuqmqq9ZC6?p=preview

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man for the solution, only thing missing is min zoom level. I want to display the text after certain zoom level. `Marker` class doesn't provide the `minZoom` property. One alternate way is to use `zoom_changed` event and use `setMap(...)` to hide/show it. Is there any better way from your side?

Comment: I believe this is a good idea to use `zoom_changed` event in order to control visibility of marker with label, you can use `setVisible()` method of marker instead of `setMap()`.

Comment: Thanks xomena. I am going to use your solution.